# select largest N of a column of each groupby group using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My df:

```
{'city1': {0: 'Chicago',
  1: 'Chicago',
  2: 'Chicago',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'Miami',
  5: 'Houston',
  6: 'Austin'},
 'city2': {0: 'Toronto',
  1: 'Detroit',
  2: 'St.Louis',
  3: 'Miami',
  4: 'Dallas',
  5: 'Dallas',
  6: 'Dallas'},
 'p234_r_c': {0: 5.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 0.5, 4: 1.0, 5: 4.0, 6: 3.0},
 'plant1_type': {0: 'COMBCYCL',
  1: 'COMBCYCL',
  2: 'NUKE',
  3: 'COAL',
  4: 'NUKE',
  5: 'COMBCYCL',
  6: 'COAL'},
 'plant2_type': {0: 'COAL',
  1: 'COAL',
  2: 'COMBCYCL',
  3: 'COMBCYCL',
  4: 'COAL',
  5: 'NUKE',
  6: 'NUKE'}}
```

I want to do 2 groupby operations and take the largest 1 of each group using column `p234_r_c`.

1st groupby = `['plant1_type', 'plant2_type', 'city1']`

2nd groupby =  `['plant1_type', 'plant2_type', 'city2']`

As such I do the following:

```
df.groupby(['plant1_type','plant2_type','city1'])['p234_r_c'].\
    nlargest(1).reset_index()


plant1_type plant2_type city1   level_3 p234_r_c
0   COAL    COMBCYCL    Chicago 3   0.5
1   COAL    NUKE        Austin  6   3.0
2   COMBCYCL    COAL    Chicago 0   5.0
3   COMBCYCL    NUKE    Houston 5   4.0
4   NUKE    COAL        Miami   4   1.0
5   NUKE    COMBCYCL    Chicago 2   2.0
```

The result of the 1st groupby makes sense. However, I am confused by the result of the 2nd groupby:

```
df.groupby(['plant1_type','plant2_type','city2'])['p234_r_c'].\
    nlargest(1).reset_index()

index   p234_r_c
0   0   5.0
1   1   4.0
2   2   2.0
3   3   0.5
4   4   1.0
5   5   4.0
6   6   3.0
```

What happened to columns `plant1_type`, `plant2_type` and `city2` in the result? Shouldnt they appear in the result just like how `plant1_type`, `plant2_type` and `city1` appeared in the result of the 1st groupby?

Comment: It's likely that you found a bug

Comment: Good find! @codingknob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I added an issue here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15272)

Theory:

> When the results of a `groupby` on a `pd.Series` returns the same `pd.Series` values, then the original index is returned.

Boiled down example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[0, 1, 2, 3]))

# returns results identical to df.A
print(df.groupby(df.A // 2).A.nsmallest(2))

# returns results out of order
print(df.groupby(df.A // 2).A.nlargest(2))

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
A   
0  1    1
   0    0
1  3    3
   2    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

I'd argue that you want these to return the same consistent index.

This is the most egregious consequence of this:

```
# most egregious
# this will be randomly different
print(df.groupby(df.A // 2).A.apply(pd.Series.sample, n=2))
```

---

returns this on one execution

```
A   
0  1    1
   0    0
1  2    2
   3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

And this on another

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Of course this never has an issue because it's impossible to return the same values as the original

```
print(df.groupby(df.A // 2).A.apply(pd.Series.sample, n=1))

A   
0  0    0
1  2    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

***Work around***
`set_index`

```
cols = ['plant1_type','plant2_type','city2']
df.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].\
    nlargest(1).reset_index()

  plant1_type plant2_type     city2  p234_r_c
0    COMBCYCL        COAL   Toronto       5.0
1    COMBCYCL        COAL   Detroit       4.0
2        NUKE    COMBCYCL  St.Louis       2.0
3        COAL    COMBCYCL     Miami       0.5
4        NUKE        COAL    Dallas       1.0
5    COMBCYCL        NUKE    Dallas       4.0
6        COAL        NUKE    Dallas       3.0
```

Comment: Nice research, in other words if no aggregation then error - `df.groupby(['plant1_type','plant2_type','city1'])['p234_r_c'].\
    nlargest(2).reset_index()`, but if `1` then works - `df.groupby(['plant1_type','plant2_type','city1'])['p234_r_c'].\
    nlargest(1).reset_index()` - there is aggreagation.

Comment: Fellas, is there any way to work around the bug in the meantime?

Comment: How do I return the index so I can use that to slice the original dataframe? I want to know which `city1` was selected for ` ['plant1_type','plant2_type','city2']` groupby and `city2` for  `['plant1_type','plant2_type','city1']` groupby

Comment: @piRSquared - the work around doesn't work in all situations. Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986261/more-bizarre-results-using-groupby-and-nlargest-in-pandas

Comment: workaround presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030468/slice-original-df-after-groupby-nlargestx-operation