# More bizarre results using: groupby and nlargest() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This question is an extension of the following post: [select largest N of a column of each groupby group using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949697/select-largest-n-of-a-column-of-each-groupby-group-using-pandas/41951566#41951566)

Lets use the same df and the workaround proposed in the selected answer. Basically, I am trying to do 2 groupby operations and select the nlargest N of each group. However as you can see below I get Errors for one of the operations.

Given that the original post discovered a bug in the code ([see here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15272)), I am wondering whether there is another bug or another manifestation of same bug?

**Unfortunately, I am at a stand still in my work until these issues are fixed and worked out. Can we kindly get some attention on this matter? I can't offer a bounty until tomorrow.**

**df:**

```
{'city1': {0: 'Chicago',
  1: 'Chicago',
  2: 'Chicago',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'Miami',
  5: 'Houston',
  6: 'Austin'},
 'city2': {0: 'Toronto',
  1: 'Detroit',
  2: 'St.Louis',
  3: 'Miami',
  4: 'Dallas',
  5: 'Dallas',
  6: 'Dallas'},
 'p234_r_c': {0: 5.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 0.5, 4: 1.0, 5: 4.0, 6: 3.0},
 'plant1_type': {0: 'COMBCYCL',
  1: 'COMBCYCL',
  2: 'NUKE',
  3: 'COAL',
  4: 'NUKE',
  5: 'COMBCYCL',
  6: 'COAL'},
 'plant2_type': {0: 'COAL',
  1: 'COAL',
  2: 'COMBCYCL',
  3: 'COMBCYCL',
  4: 'COAL',
  5: 'NUKE',
  6: 'NUKE'}}
```

You can use the above dict to generate the df: `pd.DataFrame(dct)`

**First groupby:** Seems to generate results that make sense

```
cols = ['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']
df.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index()

    city2   plant1_type plant2_type p234_r_c
0   Toronto COMBCYCL    COAL        5.0
1   Detroit COMBCYCL    COAL        4.0
2   St.Louis    NUKE    COMBCYCL    2.0
3   Miami   COAL        COMBCYCL    0.5
4   Dallas  NUKE        COAL        1.0
5   Dallas  COMBCYCL    NUKE        4.0
6   Dallas  COAL        NUKE        3.0
```

**Second groupby:** Produces an error. The only difference is `city1` is used rather than `city2`.

```
cols = ['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']
df.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index()
```

**Error result:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-443-6426182b55e1> in <module>()
----> 1 test1.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index()

C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, name, inplace)
    967         else:
    968             df = self.to_frame(name)
--> 969             return df.reset_index(level=level, drop=drop)
    970 
    971     def __unicode__(self):

C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, inplace, col_level, col_fill)
   2944                     level_values = _maybe_casted_values(lev, lab)
   2945                     if level is None or i in level:
-> 2946                         new_obj.insert(0, col_name, level_values)
   2947 
   2948         elif not drop:

C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   2447         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value)
   2448         self._data.insert(loc, column, value,
-> 2449                           allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
   2450 
   2451     def assign(self, **kwargs):

C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   3508         if not allow_duplicates and item in self.items:
   3509             # Should this be a different kind of error??
-> 3510             raise ValueError('cannot insert %s, already exists' % item)
   3511 
   3512         if not isinstance(loc, int):

ValueError: cannot insert plant2_type, already exists
```

**Lastly:**

How can I get the `city1` column in the result of groupby using `['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']` and `city2` column in the result of groupby using `['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']`?

I want to know the corresponding `city1` value for groupby using `['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']` and corresponding `city2` value for groupby using `['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']`.

**UPDATE:**

Why are the results of the following have completely different structures? The only difference is that `city2` is used in #A while `city1` is used in #B.

A)

```
cols = ['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']
test1.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1)


city2     plant1_type  plant2_type
Toronto   COMBCYCL     COAL           5.0
Detroit   COMBCYCL     COAL           4.0
St.Louis  NUKE         COMBCYCL       2.0
Miami     COAL         COMBCYCL       0.5
Dallas    NUKE         COAL           1.0
          COMBCYCL     NUKE           4.0
          COAL         NUKE           3.0
Name: p234_r_c, dtype: float64
```

B)

```
cols2 = ['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']
test1.set_index(cols2).groupby(level=cols2)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1)

city1    plant1_type  plant2_type  city1    plant1_type  plant2_type
Austin   COAL         NUKE         Austin   COAL         NUKE           3.0
Chicago  COAL         COMBCYCL     Chicago  COAL         COMBCYCL       0.5
         COMBCYCL     COAL         Chicago  COMBCYCL     COAL           5.0
         NUKE         COMBCYCL     Chicago  NUKE         COMBCYCL       2.0
Houston  COMBCYCL     NUKE         Houston  COMBCYCL     NUKE           4.0
Miami    NUKE         COAL         Miami    NUKE         COAL           1.0
Name: p234_r_c, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [76]: df.groupby(cols2)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index(level=3, drop=True).reset_index()
Out[76]:
     city1 plant1_type plant2_type  p234_r_c
0   Austin        COAL        NUKE       3.0
1  Chicago        COAL    COMBCYCL       0.5
2  Chicago    COMBCYCL        COAL       5.0
3  Chicago        NUKE    COMBCYCL       2.0
4  Houston    COMBCYCL        NUKE       4.0
5    Miami        NUKE        COAL       1.0
```

Frankly speaking I don't understand the following behavior:

```
In [77]: df.set_index(cols2).groupby(level=cols2)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1)
Out[77]:
city1    plant1_type  plant2_type  city1    plant1_type  plant2_type
Austin   COAL         NUKE         Austin   COAL         NUKE           3.0
Chicago  COAL         COMBCYCL     Chicago  COAL         COMBCYCL       0.5
         COMBCYCL     COAL         Chicago  COMBCYCL     COAL           5.0
         NUKE         COMBCYCL     Chicago  NUKE         COMBCYCL       2.0
Houston  COMBCYCL     NUKE         Houston  COMBCYCL     NUKE           4.0
Miami    NUKE         COAL         Miami    NUKE         COAL           1.0
Name: p234_r_c, dtype: float64
```

where:

```
In [78]: cols2
Out[78]: ['city1', 'plant1_type', 'plant2_type']
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. My reply to the behavior is - why should it matter which columns are selected in the groupby operation? What is the difference between `['city1', 'plant1_type', 'plant2_type']` and `['city2', 'plant1_type', 'plant2_type']`? Why does the same groupby code work for one and not the other operation?

Comment: Any idea how I can work around the current bugs to find the corresponding `city1` value for `groupby` using `['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']` and corresponding `city2` value for `groupby` using `['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']`.

Comment: The difference between ``'city1'`` and ``'city2'`` is just that in one case it is a "real" groupby operation, while in the other each group has actually size 1. Which is clearly not a justification (and that's why there's an open issue), just an explanation; then, the ``reset_index(level=3)`` suggested my @MaxU is the workaround you're looking for.

Comment: @PietroBattiston - Thank you for the explanation. So, I can do `df.loc[df.groupby(cols2)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index().level_3]` to retrieve the selected rows via the groupby from the original dataframe, where `cols2 =  ['city1', 'plant1_type', 'plant2_type']`. However, I am not sure how to do this for  `cols =  ['city2', 'plant1_type', 'plant2_type']`.

Comment: workaround presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030468/slice-original-df-after-groupby-nlargestx-operation