# slice original df after groupby().nlargest(x) operation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the problems with `groupby()` and `nlargest()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949697/select-largest-n-of-a-column-of-each-groupby-group-using-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986261/more-bizarre-results-using-groupby-and-nlargest-in-pandas). I am trying to work around the problems.

Note: for simplicity I used `nlargest(1)`, however, it could be any number of selections.

```
{'city1': {0: 'Chicago',
  1: 'Chicago',
  2: 'Chicago',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'Miami',
  5: 'Houston',
  6: 'Austin'},
 'city2': {0: 'Toronto',
  1: 'Detroit',
  2: 'St.Louis',
  3: 'Miami',
  4: 'Dallas',
  5: 'Dallas',
  6: 'Dallas'},
 'p234_r_c': {0: 5.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 0.5, 4: 1.0, 5: 4.0, 6: 3.0},
 'plant1_type': {0: 'COMBCYCL',
  1: 'COMBCYCL',
  2: 'NUKE',
  3: 'COAL',
  4: 'NUKE',
  5: 'COMBCYCL',
  6: 'COAL'},
 'plant2_type': {0: 'COAL',
  1: 'COAL',
  2: 'COMBCYCL',
  3: 'COMBCYCL',
  4: 'COAL',
  5: 'NUKE',
  6: 'NUKE',}}
```

A) groupby `city1` and return rows selected from original df

```
cols2 = ['city1','plant1_type','plant2_type']
df.loc[df2.groupby(cols2)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1).reset_index().level_3]

    city1   city2   p234_r_c    plant1_type plant2_type
6   Austin  Dallas       3.0    COAL        NUKE
3   Chicago Miami        0.5    COAL        COMBCYCL
0   Chicago Toronto      5.0    COMBCYCL    COAL
2   Chicago St.Louis     2.0    NUKE        COMBCYCL
5   Houston Dallas       4.0    COMBCYCL    NUKE
4   Miami   Dallas       1.0    NUKE        COAL
```

The above looks good

B) groupby `city2` and return rows selected from original df

Since the same code used in #A generates a bogus result if attempted for groupby of `city2`, a workaround was suggested to do the following:

```
cols = ['city2','plant1_type','plant2_type']
df.set_index(cols).groupby(level=cols)['p234_r_c'].nlargest(1)


city2     plant1_type  plant2_type
Toronto   COMBCYCL     COAL           5.0
Detroit   COMBCYCL     COAL           4.0
St.Louis  NUKE         COMBCYCL       2.0
Miami     COAL         COMBCYCL       0.5
Dallas    NUKE         COAL           1.0
          COMBCYCL     NUKE           4.0
          COAL         NUKE           3.0
```

Now how do I use this result to return the rows selected from the original df as I did in #A?

**Note**: had the original df had an additional row that made the result of `groupby.nlargest()` for `city2` have groups where at least one group had size greater than 1 then the code in `#A` can be used for `#B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something (and I agree there are bugs lurking in the pandas code here), we can bypass any difficulties relatively simply.

Method #1: use `loc` and `idxmax`:

```
In [21]: df.loc[df.groupby(cols2)["p234_r_c"].idxmax()]
Out[21]: 
     city1     city2  p234_r_c plant1_type plant2_type
6   Austin    Dallas       3.0        COAL        NUKE
3  Chicago     Miami       0.5        COAL    COMBCYCL
0  Chicago   Toronto       5.0    COMBCYCL        COAL
2  Chicago  St.Louis       2.0        NUKE    COMBCYCL
5  Houston    Dallas       4.0    COMBCYCL        NUKE
4    Miami    Dallas       1.0        NUKE        COAL

In [22]: df.loc[df.groupby(cols)["p234_r_c"].idxmax()]
Out[22]: 
     city1     city2  p234_r_c plant1_type plant2_type
6   Austin    Dallas       3.0        COAL        NUKE
5  Houston    Dallas       4.0    COMBCYCL        NUKE
4    Miami    Dallas       1.0        NUKE        COAL
1  Chicago   Detroit       4.0    COMBCYCL        COAL
3  Chicago     Miami       0.5        COAL    COMBCYCL
2  Chicago  St.Louis       2.0        NUKE    COMBCYCL
0  Chicago   Toronto       5.0    COMBCYCL        COAL
```

Method #2: sort by `p234_r_c` and use `last`:

```
In [17]: df.sort_values("p234_r_c").groupby(cols2, as_index=False).last()
Out[17]: 
     city1 plant1_type plant2_type     city2  p234_r_c
0   Austin        COAL        NUKE    Dallas       3.0
1  Chicago        COAL    COMBCYCL     Miami       0.5
2  Chicago    COMBCYCL        COAL   Toronto       5.0
3  Chicago        NUKE    COMBCYCL  St.Louis       2.0
4  Houston    COMBCYCL        NUKE    Dallas       4.0
5    Miami        NUKE        COAL    Dallas       1.0

In [18]: df.sort_values("p234_r_c").groupby(cols, as_index=False).last()
Out[18]: 
      city2 plant1_type plant2_type    city1  p234_r_c
0    Dallas        COAL        NUKE   Austin       3.0
1    Dallas    COMBCYCL        NUKE  Houston       4.0
2    Dallas        NUKE        COAL    Miami       1.0
3   Detroit    COMBCYCL        COAL  Chicago       4.0
4     Miami        COAL    COMBCYCL  Chicago       0.5
5  St.Louis        NUKE    COMBCYCL  Chicago       2.0
6   Toronto    COMBCYCL        COAL  Chicago       5.0
```

---

If you want to be able to get multiple responses as well, while nlargest and nsmallest are broken, I think it's simplest to sort and then use head or tail.  For example:

```
In [27]: df.sort_values("p234_r_c").groupby(cols, as_index=False).tail(2)
Out[27]: 
     city1     city2  p234_r_c plant1_type plant2_type
3  Chicago     Miami       0.5        COAL    COMBCYCL
4    Miami    Dallas       1.0        NUKE        COAL
2  Chicago  St.Louis       2.0        NUKE    COMBCYCL
6   Austin    Dallas       3.0        COAL        NUKE
1  Chicago   Detroit       4.0    COMBCYCL        COAL
5  Houston    Dallas       4.0    COMBCYCL        NUKE
0  Chicago   Toronto       5.0    COMBCYCL        COAL
```

Comment: Say if I use `Method#1` and do a `groupby` using only `cols = ['city1']` and want the `largest 2 (or N) of p234_r_c`. I tried the following with `N=2` and the result is the same as for `N=1`. 

`df.loc[df.groupby(cols2)["p234_r_c"].idxmax(2)]`

Comment: for `N=2`, we should have 2 rows for Chicago. i.e. the following row is missing: `Chicago Detroit 4.0 COMBCYCL COAL`

Comment: @codingknob: `idxmax` doesn't have an `n` parameter, so if there's documentation somewhere suggesting that it does, please file a bug because we need to fix it. :-(

Comment: you are correct that it does not take a `n` parameter. I just read the documentation. I just assumed that I could pass a `n` parameter. :-). So, if `idxmax` doesn't allow you to specify how many items to select then I'm back to `nlargest`, which has some sort of bugs. Not sure how to move forward

Comment: @codingknob: we can do that too-- your question suggested to me you only wanted the one.

Comment: So, right now I am tinkering and exploring my data. For simplicity I went with a selection of N=1 but it could be any number. I should have been more clear on that. Let me update

Comment: That's okay.  It takes a bit of experience to know what simplifications qualitatively change the problem.